# squeeze and unsqueeze tensor in Android (Java)

Tags: android, pytorch

I am trying to port my torchscript over from Python to Android (Java). Currently, I ran into a problem of trying to squeeze/ unsqueeze my input and output tensor in Android. In Python, here's how I did it:

```
**tensor = torch.Tensor(image_n.transpose(2, 0, 1).astype('float32')).unsqueeze(0)
tensor = tensor.to(device)**
```

output tensor:

```
 **with torch.no_grad():
    prob = model.forward(tensor)
    prediction = prob.squeeze().numpy().astype('uint8')**
```

In Android, I managed to input and output my tensors following the Pytorch tutorial as such:

```
**final Tensor inputTensor = TensorImageUtils.bitmapToFloat32Tensor(mBitmap,
            TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_MEAN_RGB, TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_STD_RGB);
  final float[] inputs = inputTensor.getDataAsFloatArray();**
```

and the output tensor:

```
**Map<String, IValue> outTensors = mModule.forward(IValue.from(inputTensor)).toDictStringKey();**
```

The problem is, without squeeze and unsqueeze, although the code managed to run, the dimensions are wrong and I didnt manage to get the correct output.

Does anyone know if there is actually squeeze/unsqueeze function for pytorch in Android?

Edit: just to add on, my input tensor has the size of (3,224,416) (an RGB image), and my out put tensor has the size of (1,1,224,416) (a grayscale image)

Comment: Any updates on this? Were you able to implement a `squeeze` function on Android?